# Heroku subdomain with cloudflare "Too many redirects"

Tags: http, heroku, dns, subdomain, cloudflare

I have three heroku applications, all under the same domain with two being subdomains.

- example.com works fine
- admin.example.com works fine
- dev.example.com does not work, and gives "Too many redirects" with 301 status
- admin and dev are setup identical

Here's my heroku setup:

[image]

And my cloudflare setup:

[image]

Some answers here on SO suggest changing SSL to "full" instead of "flexible" on cloudflare, however that results in a 525 which is only resolved by using an origin cert. My hobby dyno is for production, and I do not want to pay additional just to debug what should be working on it's own (can't use SSL on free apps).

https://help.heroku.com/GVS2BTB5/why-am-i-getting-error-525-ssl-handshake-failed-with-cloudflare-when-using-a-herokudns-com-endpoint